# Plot a function using Gnuplot with C99

Tags: c, plot, terminal, gnuplot, c99

I want to plot the sinus function with Gnuplot using C99 on CLion from JetBrains (Windows 10). I have been given a code that is supposed to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void plot(double a, double b, int nbpoints, double (*f)(double)){
    double x, h = (b-a)/nbpoints;
    /* create data file */
    FILE *data = fopen("data.txt", "w");
    for (x = a; x < b+h/2; x+=h)
        fprintf(data, "%g %g\n", x, f(x));
    fclose(data);
    /* create command file */
    FILE *cmd = fopen("cmd.txt", "w");
    fprintf(cmd, "plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with lines\n");
    fclose(cmd);
    /* execute commands in a file */
    system("gnuplot -persistent cmd.txt");
}

int main() {
    plot(0, M_PI, 100, sin);
}
```

The interpreter says that "gnuplot" is not recognised. It shows me the same message when I directly write it in the Windows terminal. Yet, I downloaded Gnuplot on my computer, and I also have Octave. Could someone help me to make this work ? Here is the [the complete project file on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xgaKZqbG7Zt4_VcSut9IZyNRLjHETKzh?usp=sharing) in case you would need the additional files of CLion.

---

**EDIT:** I have modified the path this way:

```
system("cd C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin")
```

Now, when I enter `system("gnuplot")` or `system("gnuplot.exe")`, it opens me another window with gnuplot. Half of my problem is solved. However, I still can't directly write in gnuplot from C, and the command `system("gnuplot>plot sin(x)")` doesn't work. How could I use the gnuplot terminal without interrupting the code, and make it only pop the plot graph ?

```
C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin>gnuplot plot sin(x)

line 0: Cannot load input from 'sin(x)'
^
"plot" line 1: invalid command
```

Comment: What has this to do with C? *It shows me the same message when I directly write it in the Windows terminal.*

Comment: `I have been given a code that is supposed to work` Have you tried contacting the supplier for help?

Comment: Have you installed gnuplot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) This is one of many answers with the same principle: Commands are only found without a full path on the command line, if you have their path in `PATH`.

Comment: I have installed gnuplot indeed, the supplier is not available

Comment: @thebusybee thanks, the path problem is now solved, I edited my question (can open gnuplot but not execute commands in it without interrupting the C code execution)

Comment: It finally made it work ! I'll write an answer to explain

Answer (score 1):

The line `system("gnuplot -persistent cmd.txt");` has to be replaced by

```
system("cd C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin && gnuplot --persist -e plot-sin(x)");
```

Indeed:

1. The `PATH` set was not correct (see ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4492979/19930448)), it had to be redirected to the `gnuplot` file using the `cd` command.
2. It was at first impossible to use the `gnuplot` interface in one single command line without interrupting the program. The commands as `gnuplot plot sin(x)` or `gnuplot>plot sin(x)` didn't work. A look at [gnuplot: line 1: invalid command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10937510/19930448) showed me that the `--persist -e` commands needed to be used:

> using '-e' is the same thing as putting the stuff in singe quotes into a temporary file

> The --persist makes it so the plot stays on your screen (which you'll want since I doubt you're saving it to a file)

Moreover, a `-` had to be placed between the `plot` command and `sin(x)`.